# Как отсортировать столбец по данным из другого столбца?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, pandas, join

В таблице `cars` есть столбец `ID_person` - владельцев авто. Есть таблица `person`, в ней столбецы `ID`, `weight` и `height`. Задача, отсортировать таблицу `cars` по Вес/рост владельца. Проблема в том, что размер таблицы person 20000 уникальных людей, а `cars` - 15000 при этом у одного человека может и не быть машины или быть несколько.

Я пробовал создать столбец `w/h` разделив столбец `Weight` на `Height` и отсортировать таблицу `people` по столбцу `w/h` с помощью `people.sort_values['w/h']` и пробовал отсортировать `cars` так `cars.sort_values[people['ID']]`. Но ничего не вышло.

Вот пример таблицы `cars`:

```
 ID  ID_person Model
  0    3       LADA
  1    2      Toyota
  2    1      Toyota
  3    3      Daewoo
  4    4      Subaru
```

Вот пример таблицы people после сортировки по `w/h`:

```
 ID      Name         Height   Weight          h_w
  5 Журавлёвa Ия       184      40    0.21739130434782608
  4 Пестовa Снежана    183      40    0.2185792349726776
  1 Исаковa Мария      184      41    0.22282608695652173
  2 Зуевa Альбина      179      40    0.22346368715083798
  3 Горбуновa Эдита    183      41    0.22404371584699453
```

Надо получить `cars` в таком виде:

```
 ID, ID_person Model
  4    4      Subaru
  2    1      Toyota
  1    2      Toyota
  0    3       LADA
  3    3      Daewoo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
res = (cars
       .merge(pers.eval("x=Weight/Height"), 
              left_on="ID_person", right_on="ID", 
              suffixes=["", "_2"])
        .sort_values("x")
        [cars.columns])
```

---

результат:

```
In [80]: res
Out[80]:
   ID  ID_person   Model
4   4          4  Subaru
3   2          1  Toyota
2   1          2  Toyota
0   0          3    LADA
1   3          3  Daewoo
```

Comment: Большое спасибо